# Set value on a new term based on a vocabulary custom field

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

I want to set the value of a field of a term based on a custom field set on the vocabulary. Basically if the vocabulary `promote_to_index` field is checked I want to the `field_index_page` of the term checked.

I understand I have to write a hook like but I don't understand how to get the value of the vocabulary custom field

```
function polaris_drupal_taxonomy_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_id) {

    case 'taxonomy_term_category_form':
    case 'taxonomy_term_article_type_form':
    case 'taxonomy_term_main_purpose_form':
    case 'taxonomy_term_tags_form':
    case 'taxonomy_term_content_partnership_form':
    case 'taxonomy_term_traffic_source_form':
    case 'taxonomy_term_client_form':
      $form['field_index_page']['widget']['value']['#default_value'] = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extra validation step to those forms that checks and changes the value accordingly like so.

```
function polaris_drupal_taxonomy_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'taxonomy_term_category_form':
    case 'taxonomy_term_article_type_form':
    case 'taxonomy_term_main_purpose_form':
    case 'taxonomy_term_tags_form':
    case 'taxonomy_term_content_partnership_form':
    case 'taxonomy_term_traffic_source_form':
    case 'taxonomy_term_client_form':
      $form['#validate'][] = '_polaris_drupal_add_field_index_page';
  }
}

function _polaris_drupal_add_field_index_page(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $promote_to_index = $form_state->getValue('promote_to_index');
  if ($promote_to_index['value']) {
    $form_state->setValue('field_index_page', [ 'value' => TRUE ]);
  }
  else {
    $form_state->setValue('field_index_page', [ 'value' => FALSE ]);
  }
}
```

This will check the field **promote_to_index** of the form and set the field **field_index_page** before executing the submit handlers of the form.